# Fetching and overwriting a specific json object in Typescript

Tags: json, typescript

Edit: Looks like I was barking up the wrong tree and trying to overcomplicate this (I got mixed up with other things I was trying at the same time, blame the ADHD I guess)

After @Marc's comments I went in and changed the JSON file to this:

```
{
   "ProductA": "tbd",
   "ProductB": "tbd2",
   "ProductC": "tbd3"
}
```

And changed my function to this:

```
getReferenceNumber(productName){
    fs.readFile('./filepath.json', 'utf-8', (err, jsonString) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            try {
                const data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
                return data.productName;
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("Error parsing JSON:", err);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And finally called my function like this:

```
const referenceNumber = jsonHelper.getReferenceNumber("ProductA");
console.log(referenceNumber);
```

I didn't get any errors this time but in the console I was expecting it to return "rbq" and instead it returns undefined. Is this because I'm passing it "ProductA" as a string? And if so what's should I be passing it instead?

---

Original Post:

This is a followup to a question I asked earlier today about reading/writing from a JSON file for Typescript.

I'm very new to interacting with JSON files and trying to fetch an object from a JSON file with one function that would be passed something to identify the object and overwritten by another function that would be passed that same ID and the text to overwrite it with.

Following tutorials I've found online exactly would mean having a different JSON file for each product I'm working with, which would lead to 29 different small files and I'd like to avoid that by having all the data in one JSON file with someway to identify it.

this is the format I was trying for the JSON file that the 29 products will use

```
{
    "ProductA": [{"id": 1, "rbq": "tbd"}],
    "ProductB": [{"id": 2, "rbq": "tbd2"}],
    "ProductC": [{"id": 3, "rbq": "tbd3"}]
}
```

I try to fetch what the "rbq" number (also known as the reference number) of a certain product with this function

```
    getReferenceNumber(idNumber){
        fs.readFile('./filepath.json', 'utf-8', (err, jsonString) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                try {
                    const data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
                    const jsonObject = data.id(idNumber);
                    return jsonObject.rbq;
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log("Error parsing JSON:", err);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

called like this

```
    const referenceNumber = jsonHelper.getReferenceNumber(1);
    console.log(referenceNumber);
```

I'd expect this to output "tbd" to the console, but I get this error instead:
Error parsing JSON: TypeError: data.id is not a function
so it seems like I'm not identifying the JSON object correctly by it's id, and that's where I need help.

I haven't gotten far enough to run the function to overwrite the RBQ number, but it uses the same id based call so it won't work for the same reason. Here it is though

```
    updateReferenceNumber(idNumber, newReference){
        this.jsonReader('./filepath.json', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                const jsonObject = data.id(idNumber);
                jsonObject.rbq = newReference;
                fs.writeFile('./filepath.json', JSON.stringify(data), err => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your JSON object doesn't have an `id` field. And do you mean to be nesting your product objects inside a single-element array?  To get what you want, you'd need to do something like `data.ProductA.find(x=>x.id===1).rbq`. Or since all of your arrays are a single element, you don't even need to find by `id`. You can just grab element 0: `data.ProductA[0].rbq`. But I don't assume the single-element approach is your intent.

Comment: I don't really know what you're trying to achieve. But it looks to me like you don't need the array `[ ]`.

Comment: I'm pretty in the dark here cuz it's very new to me so I may be doing things very inefficiently, but getting rid of the id entirely, calling the function with the productName instead of id, then doing `data.productName[0].rbq` might work, let me try and report back

edit: I think I'm being dumb and overthinking it. This is a result of me getting tangled up with other things I tried at the same time, I think I can just get rid of the array and pass the product name to the function. Let me try that and I'll comment back

Comment: Sorry looks like code is very ugly in the comments, let me edit the post to talk about my results and followup question

Comment: Added results and followup question to post

Answer (score 0):

The question itself is getting a bit confusing to answer because it hasn't been streamlined. However, what I *think* you're missing is that when you try to get the JSON object's value based on a variable name, you need to reference it within `[`square brackets`]`.

Here's a very simplified version of what you're trying to do, but I'm setting up the JSON object string explicitly rather than by `readFile()`:

```js
const jsonString = `{
  "ProductA": "tbd",
  "ProductB": "tbd2",
  "ProductC": "tbd3"
}`;

function getReferenceNumber(productName) {
  const data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  return data[productName]; // <-- Notice this reference
}


console.log("ProductA", getReferenceNumber("ProductA"));
console.log("ProductB", getReferenceNumber("ProductB"));
console.log("ProductC", getReferenceNumber("ProductC"));
```

So in your function you can change the reference in the same way to get your result.

Furthermore, I would recommend you start breaking down the problem into smaller components when you get stuck. I.e., because I hard-coded the JSON object in my example, it was easy to get the syntax right for object reference while not contending with `readFile()`'s nuances. Then I could expand this to do the `readFile()` and log the outputs from that. And so forth. As you reduce the uncertain parts (e.g., with a hard-coded JSON string), you can home in on where your problem is and work one small piece at a time.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, I'll try to keep things smaller from now on.

To try to narrow down the issue, I commented out the return statement in my function and instead just used console.log commands on a few different versions of "data", and you're right, adding the brackets to the productName variable has it outputting what I expect to the log. So I got rid of the log statements and went back to "return data[productName]", but that's back to giving me undefined even though the same thing in the log was working.

Comment: (ran out of characters in the last comment) So after troubleshooting that I guess the problem is either in my return statement or my actual call of the function in my test. 

My return statement is now:
`return data[productName];`

and my call is this:
`const referenceNumber = jsonHelper.getReferenceNumber("ProductA")`

and to make sure the call worked I have a simple log statement under it (which outputs "undefined" atm:
`console.log(referenceNumber);`